# How do I fix this VirtualBox install issue

Tags: virtualbox

I've been trying to setup Ubuntu in VirtualBox and can't seem to get it to work. I haven't ran into this issue in the past.

To try to fix the problem I uninstalled VirtualBox and the Ubuntu ISO then I re-downloaded them and tried to reinstall them. I keep getting the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Did you enable virtualization in your computer's UEFI settings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while trying to start Virtual Linux Machine on Virtual Box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274739/error-while-trying-to-start-virtual-linux-machine-on-virtual-box)